# Find out if a user liked specific comment

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have the following Post class:

```
public class Post
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}
  public IList<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}

public class Comment
{
  public int OrderNumber {get;set;} //kind of CommentId
  public string AuthorId {get;set;}
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public IList<string> Voters {get;set;} //Ids of users who liked the post
}
```

There could be thousands of likes for each comment but I need to display only the quantity of them on the client so I created the following index:

```
Map = posts => from post in posts
               select new {
                            Id = post.Id,
                            Content = post.Content, 
                            Comments = post.Comments.Select(x => 
                              new CommentProjection {
                                AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                                Text = x.Text,
                                VotersCount = x.VotersCount
                                                    }),
                          };
```

The problem is I need to highlight those comments that a user has already liked. Is there a way to modify above index to add this information into query results?

Comment: Seems like it's a problem for many web sites. Some don't have this feature at all, others visualize you like only right after it was placed but if you refresh a page, nothing specific will be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the other way, keep track of the comments on the user, so you can show the comments they liked.

Comment: I feel like it's a right way to go but could you please be more specific about the idea?

Comment: Keep the comments that a user liked in the user's document.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a separate entity called `Votes` ? It could have 3 simple fields, a foreign key to your user's table and another on your comments table. A 3rd one (bit) to indicate whether this is a downvote or an upvote (like).

You could then query this table directly and easily (by filtering on the user ID and on those with an "upvote")